# Integral of absolute value of polynomial?

Tags: integration, polynomials, roots

Let $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ be integer irreducible polynomials where $b$ is U-shaped in the interval mentioned below and has 2 distinct real zeros. The zeros of $b$ cannot be expressed by radicals.
Also $b$ is the derivative of $a$ and $b$ has degree prime of type 7 mod 8.

Is it possible that there exists a nonzero integer $m$ such that the interval $[-m,m]$ contains the two zeros of $b$ and the integral from $-m$ to $m$ of the absolute value of $b(x)$ $dx$ can be given in rootform?

Comment: What's rootform?

Comment: @joriki : wild guess would be "expressible by radicals"? But it deserves clarification...

Comment: If $b$ has odd degree, its graph *can't* be U-shaped.

Comment: Ah sorry , i mean U shaped in the interval.

Comment: If $\alpha,\beta$ are the two roots of $b$, then 
$$\int_{-m}^m|b(x)|\,\mathrm dx = \int_{-m}^mb(x)\,\mathrm dx-2\int_{\alpha}^\beta b(x)\,\mathrm dx=a(m)-a(-m)-2a(\beta)+2a(\alpha) $$
So the question is whether $a(\alpha)-a(\beta)$ can be expressed by radicals.

Comment: right , so what do we know about this ?